# Show div on Image click

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I'm trying to hide a div in my web page until an image is clicked. Currently I am able to click the button and have tried to use javascript to do do this.

Unfortunately the div I tried to attach it to is not responding to this.

I have attached an image below with the image I'm trying to use to click to access the bottom section of the web page labeled "Laptops and Macbooks" I want that section to be hidden until the image is clicked.

I have attached the code below that I have been trying, along with the jsfiddle of the entire webpage: https://jsfiddle.net/2j4b4bdn/4/

any tips or advice would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Web page]

```
  <button id="toggleBtn">
        <img src="multiple.png" class="img-responsive"

             width="200px" class="img-responsive" style="margin: 0 auto;">
            </button>

<script> 

var elementToClick = document.querySelector(".togglebtn");
var elementToShow = document.querySelector(".box1");

if(elementToClick){
    elementToClick.addEventListener("click", showElement)
}

function showElement(){
    elementToShow.classList.add("show");
}
    </script>


      <div class="box1" id="box1"> 



<div> <img src="laptop.png" class="laptop"> </div>


<div class="bottomtext">Please enter a figure for the number of individual laptops/macbooks that you would like to insure in each price range.  Where you dont want cover with a particular price range, please leave bank.</div>




<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="">

        <div class="col-xs-2" id="p1">0</div>

           <p class=Text1>Up to £500 <br>How many would you like to insure?</p>

        <div class="col-xs-2 col-half-offset" id="p2">0</div>
         <div style="position:absolute; left:10rem;">
          <p class=Text2>Up to £500 <br>How many would you like to insure?</p></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-half-offset" id="p3">0</div>
         <div style="position:absolute; left:10rem;">
             <p class=Text3>Up to £500 <br>How many would you like to insure?</p> </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-half-offset" id="p4">0</div>
         <div style="position:absolute; left:10rem;">
             <p class=Text4>Up to £500 <br>How many would you like to insure?</p></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-half-offset" id="p5">0</div>
         <div style="position:absolute; left:10rem;">
             <p class=Text5>Up to £500 <br>How many would you like to insure?</p></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Consider making a trivial example to test your implementation rather than trying to do it inside an existing webpage. This will make your question more useful for future readers. (And for answerers to answer)

Comment: But surely it's possible to implement it directly on a webpage ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, using jquery:

```js
$("#showDiv").click(function() {
  $("#test").css("display", "inline-block");
  
});
```

```css
#test {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="showDiv" height="100px" src="http://imgsv.imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/zoom/normalzoom/af-s_dx_18-140mmf_35-56g_ed_vr/img/sample/sample1_l.jpg">

<div id="test" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Chris! So I just have add these instead of my existing code ? And adjust the id's and classes to the Ines you've added ?

Comment: Yes, you will need to change this to your implementation.  I tried to give a very general example of how to accomplish this task.

Comment: Great I'll give it a try! If it doesn't work I'll upload a js fiddle, and see if I'm going wrong in some area

Comment: Hi @Chrisz would you be able to check this js fiddle out?  I tried adapting my code and implementing what you suggested however it still doesn't work https://jsfiddle.net/2j4b4bdn/8/ Its hidden the div but it doesnt open on click

Comment: I would recommend splitting up your `js`, `css` and `html`, makes troubleshooting much easier. Happy programming!

Answer (score 1):

You have several errors causing a bit of a jam. Boiling it down to the bones, there are two main issues:

**1. You are not referencing the actual button.**

In your HTML, your button element looks like this:

```
<button id="toggleBtn">...</button>
```

This does not correspond to your javascript:

```
var elementToClick = document.querySelector(".togglebtn");
```

In javascript you are referencing an element with a *class* of `togglebtn`, not an *id* (as your actual element). Also, javascript is case sensitive, so `toggleBtn` and `togglebtn` will not match. I'd suggest you correct your HTML to:

```
<button class="togglebtn">...</button>
```

**2. You are applying a class that doesn't exist**

When the button is clicked, you are applying the class `show` to `.box1`. However, there is no class named `show` in your CSS.

Add this  following to your current CSS:

```
.show {
    display: block;
}
.box1 {
    display: none;
    /* ... the rest of the CSS declarations from .box1 here  */
}
```

**Show or toggle?**

In addition to these errors, you are currently using `classList.add()`. That's completely fine if you only want to show the element once, but if what you're actually trying to do is to toggle the visibility (on and off), you can change this to `classList.toggle()`.

**Example**

Here's an example of how you can do it:

```js
var elementToClick = document.querySelector(".togglebtn");
var elementToShow = document.querySelector(".box1");

if(elementToClick) {
    elementToClick.addEventListener("click", showElement)
}

function showElement(){
    elementToShow.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
.box1 {
  display: none;
}
.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button class="togglebtn">Button</button>
<div class="box1" id="box1">This is box1</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your element should start with a display value of none:

```
display:none;
```

In your fiddle the 'show' class is being added as expected when the toggleBtn is clicked but by default div elements already have a display of block.

You could just add `display:none` to the box1 then add show to update the style to `display:block` then remove the show class when it's clicked again or just toggle the display css property like this.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GyyRPx

```
function toggleBox() {
  //use var if you are planning on running straight in browser
  const box = document.getElementById('box');
  const toggled = window.getComputedStyle(box).display === "block" ? "none" : "block";

  box.style.display = toggled;
}

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', toggleBox);
```

Comment: Hi @zezogregory thanks for the reply , I've updated my code https://jsfiddle.net/2j4b4bdn/5/  so do I just add display none to css of box1 ?

Comment: Take a look at @agrm's answer I feel he should have been given the accepted answer

Answer (score -1):

Just add the click event to the img directly and handle accordingly:

```
document.getElementById('myImg').onclick = function(e) {
    document.getElementById('myDiv').style.display = 'block';
}
```

I would recommend using specific ids for the elements for easier manipulation of elements.

Comment: Thanks ThatJSman, so add that onto this    <img src="replacement.png" width="200px" class="img-responsive" style="margin: 0 auto;"> 
   ?

Comment: I tried doing what you said @ThatJSMan but it didn't work, I've uploaded a js fiddle,  https://jsfiddle.net/2j4b4bdn/5/ would you mind pointing out where i'm going wrong?

Comment: Add the id "myImg" to the image and the id "myDiv" to the div element and remove the button.

Comment: Hi @ThatJSman I just did and it still didn't work, would you mind checking out this js fiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/2j4b4bdn/7/

Comment: You need to wrap in with window.onload = function(){ //insert here } otherwise document is undefined

Comment: Hi @ThatJSMan , like so ? window.onload = document.getElementById('myImg').onclick = function(e) {
    document.getElementById('myDiv').style.display = 'block';
}

Comment: You also need to have the function(){} around the code. window.onload = function(){ document.getElementById('myImg...'block'; }

Comment: ah okay!   would you mind making the changes to the jsfiddle?, jsfiddle.net/2j4b4bdn/7  I'm not sure I fully understand how to implement what your suggesting (as im a bit of a rookie) and dont want to keep wasting your time :)

Comment: You'd just use the code: window.onload = function(){ document.getElementById('myImg').onclick = function(e) { document.getElementById('myDiv').style.display = 'block'; }}

Comment: Still doesn't work :/ when i click the image nothing happens and the bottom section doesn't stay hidden

Comment: Hmm...it worked for me once I made the change. Perhaps the div element isn't properly styled and doesn't show up as you expect. In that case, you'd have to modify the div element.

Comment: Damn it! Sorry to keep wasting your time! are you able to send me like an updated jsfiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/2j4b4bdn/9/ with the code you're specifying?

Comment: I just noticed that you have the box wrapped in another div element that is hidden with id "test". Maybe you want to show that instead. I checked and the issue isn't the JS, it's the box itself. It'll take longer to read through the entire sample code to determine where the real issue is.

Comment: Ah okay, what would you suggest doing ?